# ListView pulltorefresh activityindicator is freezing when app is toggled between background and foreground

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am implementing list view for my form page on my Xamarin forms app. Enabled pull to refresh for the same.

Whenever the list is pulled activity indicator starts animating and I start a background Task. Now when the app is sent to the background by pressing the home button and brought back to the foreground by clicking app icon on homepage or task menu, activity indicator freezes. But background Task is still running and when it finishes, I call

```
    IsRefreshing = false;
```

and it behaves normally, activity indicator goes away and listview is moved up.

how to make activityindicator resume animation again after coming to the foreground? Seeing this on iOS only, Android works fine

Comment: What is `IsRefreshing` (starting with a capital `I`?) and why do you mention it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this

```
IsRefreshing = true;
try{
    // Your task running here. You can also implement catch and display it on DisplayAlert
}finally{
    IsRefreshing = false;
}
```

If you want to put a method or request when your app or page is on appearing, you should try this

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    // put something here when app is on appearing
}
```

or this one inside the App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    // Handle when your app resumes
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect exactly what is my issue. When Task is running and we move app to background and bring back to foreground, the activityindicator above listview stops animating

Comment: I added some hint or additional ideas